# How do I get an up/parent button in Nautilus, without using breadcrumbs?

Tags: nautilus

Similar question here:
[How to get back the »open parent« button in 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62952/how-to-get-back-the-open-parent-button-in-11-10)

However, I want always-use-location-entry to be true. So I am not using breadcrumbs.

The shortkeys, both <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd>, are quite helpful. However, since I'm mainly using my mouse in Nautilus, I'd much prefer to actually have a button present that I can click. Then I don't have to switch between keyboard and mouse all the time.

Is there a way to add this button/functionality, while keeping always-use-location-entry to be true?

Another workable solution would be to use both breadcrumbs and the location-entry; so a parent is clickable, but I can also type a path directly.

Comment: There is a patch for nautilus to add the up button to the toolbar: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1904510

Comment: You could use nemo, it's a fork of nautilus and offers the desired feature (and more).

Answer (score 16):

Update 2012-01-27: An (unofficial) patch has been created to provide this functionality
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1904510

At the time the question was asked, you had two options, which I retain below for those who don't want to patch and build their own version of Nautilus.

1. With always-use-location-entry true, there is no button for the parent folder. You can use any of the following:

   - Use the menu-bar (Go->Open Parent)
   - Use the keyboard shortcuts (Alt+Up or Backspace)
2. With always-use-location-entry false, you will see breadcrumbs to show a higher level folder. To type a location, you must:

   - Press Ctrl+L
   - Use the Go->Location menu option

Regardless of which you decide to use, I would suggest giving some love and support to the bugs on both the Ubuntu project and the Gnome project:

- https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=662243
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/885592

Comment: You could also press Ctrl+L, type "..", and press Enter to go up one level. In a file open dialog, type ".." into the Location box.

Comment: I'm amazed this hasn't been fixed yet.

Answer (score 4):

Solely using the mouse don't see much to do except, -  I find the right click on the back arrow icon to be quite useful, should list all folders you accessed to get where you are

Not quite the same but handy